# Elastic Search - Phrase Matching using Java

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a Phrase matching to find similar Phrases.

Eg. Name field has following entries and all 3 should be evaluated to same :

1. "USA Tech Company"
2. "USA Tech Company Alabama"
3. "USA Tech Company California"

Can you suggest a Java code that uses Phrase matcher or something similar to suggest that above entries in the Name field are same ( possibly higher score)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use match query using "[phrase](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_phrase)" type or "[phrase_prefix](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix)" type for your case.
In Java client, Elasticsearch provides two kinds of method you can use.

- QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery(name, text);
- QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery(name, text);

Try to test the scripts below to check the result.

```
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ap100/example/1" -d '{
    "name": "USA Tech Company"
}'
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ap100/example/2" -d '{
    "name": "USA Tech Company Alabama"
}'
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ap100/example/3" -d '{
    "name": "USA Tech Company California"
}'

curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/ap100/example/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "name": {
                "type": "phrase",
                "query": "usa tech company",
                "slop": 2
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/ap100/example/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "name": {
                "type": "phrase_prefix",
                "query": "usa tech company"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```